# Django how to make a url that looks like 'a/main' or 'b/main' or 'c/main'?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a url that can either be

```
hello/main
goodbye/main
random/main
```

The url should look something like this:

```
url(r'^(hello|goodbye|random)/main$', view.as_view())
```

Then I should be able to get which value it(a, b or c) is from the args to the view.